# Visual Studio Team Services Basic Build and Deploy

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I am trying to get a very basic build and release process going using Visual Studio Team Services.

I have created a bare bones Build that uses all default steps and settings for "Visual Studio".

Looks as though my problem is that no files are being copied in the "Copy Files To" step. it's Contents field = **\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)** (by default)

My project isn't being built to a bin directory though so no files are found to copy.

How do I get my web application project via Team Services to package only required files to a location so team services can find and copy only those required to deploy?

Comment: I was missing the following MSBuild arguments which does the website packaging for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the following "MSBuild arguments" in the MSBuild task which does the website packaging for me.

/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\"